# Is there a reason the event handler SystemEvents.SessionSwitch in my backgroundservice doesn't work

Tags: c#, event-handling, c#-6.0

I am completely new to background services or to the library I'm using to detect if there is a Session Switch.
I made a new service that works when I run it in visual studio, and the service also works as far as it does the start part (sends to the database that the user is logged in) and doesn't crash (keeps running), but it never picks up the session switch. Unfortunately, because the app doesn't crash, the logger shows no information.
Here's my code:

`
using BackGroundService.TransferTracker.EmployeeCache;
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace BackGroundService.TransferTracker
{
public sealed class WindowsBackgroundService : BackgroundService
{

```
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        try
        {
            while (stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);

            throw;
        }
    }

    public override async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        EmployeeStatus.UpdateEmployeeStatus("Logged In");
        SystemEvents.SessionSwitch += SystemEventsOnSessionSwitch;

        await base.StartAsync(cancellationToken);
    }

    public override async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        SystemEvents.SessionSwitch -= SystemEventsOnSessionSwitch;
        await base.StopAsync(cancellationToken);
    }

    private void SystemEventsOnSessionSwitch(object sender, SessionSwitchEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Reason)
        {
            case SessionSwitchReason.SessionUnlock:
            case SessionSwitchReason.SessionLogon:
                EmployeeStatus.UpdateEmployeeStatus("Logged In");
                break;

            case SessionSwitchReason.SessionLogoff:
                EmployeeStatus.UpdateEmployeeStatus("Logged Out");
                break;
            case SessionSwitchReason.SessionLock:
                EmployeeStatus.UpdateEmployeeStatus("Logged In (Locked)");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

}

`

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

I've tried several ways of adding the task in the ExecuteAsync but that didn't make it trigger either. I've been looking for other solutions, but I'm afraid I can't find any information.

Comment: Taken from the [docu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.systemevents.sessionswitch?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) "This event is only raised if the message pump is running. In a Windows service, unless a hidden form is used or the message pump has been started manually, this event will not be raised."